# Dynamic queries with BigQuery from R

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I want to subset my data based on a list of items I'm looping through, and add the item that is currently indexed to the query I'm sending to BigQuery from `R`.

```
ex.
Item
001
002
003

i=2 => item '002'
```

instead of having to manually put `002`, I want to be able to construct the following query:

```
sql_string <- "SELECT * FROM MAN WHERE item_code = item[i]"
```

But currently, I have an argument type mismatch. Could someone show me how this is done through the `bigrquery` package?

Comment: I can't comment on the bigrquery part but the error message means that your variables are different types. From your description, I think replacing item_code with cast(item_code as STRING) might help but it's hard to know without a sample of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasting the sql together may work, but for security reasons, it's an unsafe practice.  This is described in https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/ and almost any resource discussing "sql injection".

This code is adapted from https://db.rstudio.com/databases/big-query/, using your query of the `man` table.

```
library(bigrquery)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  bigrquery::dbi_driver(),
  dataset = "noaa_gsod",
  project = "bigquery-public-data",
  billing = project
)

# big_vector is defined somewhere before this snippet.
for(i in big_vector) {
  ds_man <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM MAN WHERE item_code = ?")
  DBI::dbBind(ds_man, list(item[i]))
  DBI::dbFetch(ds_man)
  DBI::dbClearResult(ds_man)
}

DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

I've never run against BigQuery, so post a comment if this doesn't work.

(Even if sql injection never an issue for your specific application, some people following this example will have this vulnerability.)

Comment: Thanks for raising the concern on sql injection. Indeed, it should not be the case in my example, however, keeping in mind that you never know how your code will be used in the end, it is indeed a good idea to follow this practice.

Answer (score 1):

the  paste function did the job

```
sql_string <- paste("SELECT * FROM MAN WHERE item_code =", item[i] )
```

Comment: I think the last part of your code didn't make it into this answer.